# pip installed module but python gives Import error

Tags: python, pip

I have installed `grequests` using

```
pip install grequests
```

when I ran my script, It gave this error:

```
ImportError: No module named grequests
```

So, I checked something like this:

```
pip --version //output: pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

and

```
python -m pip --version //output: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

When I do:

```
python -m pip install grequests
 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/grequests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement grequests (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for grequests
```

Comment: Check that you're using the correct version of Python.

Comment: I am using python2.7

Comment: You have two pythons installed: the system one, part of MacOS, and the brewed one, which you've installed with `brew install python`. Your `pip` command points to brewed python, and you're running your script with the system python. Adjust your `PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` so brewed python is selected when you run `python ...`, or alias `python` command to the brewed python executable.

Comment: I have installed python3 and pip3 and using it now. working as expected. 
Thanks for the help anyway.